# Substring to Get Text after Second Period in Powershell

Tags: powershell, substring

I am working with a Substring that will give me everything before the 2nd '.' I've worked with substrings before to get everything before the 1st '.'

```
$id = $file.Substring(0, $File.LastIndexof('.'))
```

and it works perfectly. For this second substring this is what I have thus far

```
$netVerShort = $netVer.Substring(0,  2nd ('.'))
```

but I'm certain this isn't right. The value I get from $netVer is 2.0.5727 and with this second substring I'm trying to get it to return 2.0

Comment: How is this question different from your [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27510561/1630171)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not necessarily the most efficient approach but you could use split for this and rejoin the elements you are looking for. Take the following string:

```
$stuff = "This.is the end. Bagels. are. awesome."
```

Now we split that on periods and then take the first two elements and join them back together.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> $stuff.Split(".",3)
This
is the end
 Bagels. are. awesome.
```

The 3 is to say that we only need to return 3 elements. Depending on how many periods you have this might be a good idea as to not waste time. Next we need to join the 2 elements you want.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> ($stuff.Split(".",3) | Select -Index 0,1) -join "."
This.is the end
```

To address your `.SubString()` approach you would need to check twice since you would have the first one then you would need to find the second.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> $stuff.Substring($stuff.IndexOf(".",$stuff.IndexOf(".") + 1))
. Bagels. are. awesome.
```

Get the first index with `$stuff.IndexOf(".")` then add 1 to the return. Using that value as the start index for the search of the next period. Then use that for the substring. Add 1 to the entire thing if you dont want the period to be part of the return.

Answer (score 14):

If you are working with version numbers, the `System.Version` class that can do the parsing for you:

```
$netVer = "2.0.5727"
$v = [version]$netVer
$netVerShort = "$($v.Major).$($v.Minor)"
```

will yield "2.0"

Answer (score 9):

So, this is the first `'.'`:

```
$x.IndexOf('.')
```

This is everything after the first `'.'`:

```
$x.Substring($x.IndexOf('.') + 1)
```

This is the first `'.'` after the first `'.'` (so, the second period):

```
$x.Substring($x.IndexOf('.') + 1).IndexOf('.')
```

So, the length of string we want is:

```
$x.IndexOf('.') + 1 + $x.Substring($x.IndexOf('.') + 1).IndexOf('.')
```

So, we want the string, starting from the beginning with a length long enough to reach just before the second period:

```
$x.Substring(0, $x.IndexOf('.') + 1 + $x.Substring($x.IndexOf('.') + 1).IndexOf('.'))
```

So:

```
PS C:\> $x = '198.51.100.5';
PS C:\> $x.Substring(0, $x.IndexOf('.') + 1 + $x.Substring($x.IndexOf('.') + 1).IndexOf('.'))
198.51
```

Comment: This was really useful for me :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation of Matt's answer above, but using slightly different semantics. Again, we split and join the string:

```
("this.is the end.bagels.are good.oh yes" -split "\.")[0..1] -join "."
```

In this, we've replaced the `select -index` that Matt used with an array range `[0..1]` and use the native `-split` and `-join` operators. Is it any more efficient than Matt's? In terms of keystrokes, it is :-) But computationally probably not much (if any) difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. Do you need to include the 2nd period? Do you want everything before the 2nd period or just what's between the 1st and 2nd period?

```
"th1 s.!s.a.test" -replace '^(.+?\..+?)\..*', '$1'
th1 s.!s
```

If you need to seperate them you could try this:

```
"th1 s.!s.a.test" -replace '^(.+?)\.(.+?)\..*', '$1'
th1 s

"th1 s.!s.a.test" -replace '^(.+?)\.(.+?)\..*', '$2'
!s
```

If you only need the major and minor version, try:

```
"2.0.5727" -replace '^(\d+\.\d+).*', '$1'
2.0
```

Personally, I would use the proper .Net solution that [mjolinor suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27510788/702944) in your other question (which this is kinda a duplicate of).