# Edit (split) string in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How can I split the string "FOLDER03631140M/1/7010-win10-A01-GR1XM.CAB" cleanly at the second "/" or discard the front part of the string? Theoretically, this is halfway clear to me, but desperately easy to do... Unfortunately, I still lack the routine...

Result should be that only "7010-win10-A01-GR1XM.CAB" remains from the string.

I am happy about your support

Greetings
Nils

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Substring to Get Text after Second Period in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513886/substring-to-get-text-after-second-period-in-powershell)

Comment: `("FOLDER03631140M/1/7010-win10-A01-GR1XM.CAB" -split '/')[-1]` --> `7010-win10-A01-GR1XM.CAB`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a Path and take out only the last part (filename) Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305545/split-a-path-and-take-out-only-the-last-part-filename-powershell): `Split-Path -Leaf FOLDER03631140M/1/7010-win10-A01-GR1XM.CAB`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$string = "The string"
$string.split("/")[2]
```

Here .split returns an array and we have now 3 elements. Now we can get that part in the 2nd element.